# multiple visual effects on one event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jrails

I have a code that looks like this.

```
<%= link_to_remote "View results",
{
    :update=>"uxUpdateDiv" ,
    :url=>{:controller=>"exam", :action=>"results"}  ,
    :loading=>visual_effect(:appear, "uxcLoader", :duration=> 0.1),
    :before =>visual_effect(:fade, "uxUpdateDiv", :duration => 0.1),
    :complete => visual_effect(:appear, "uxUpdateDiv", :duration => 1.5 ),
    :success=>visual_effect(:fade, "uxcLoader", :duration=> 1)
}
%>
```

what happens here is not good enough for me.

I want to add multiple effects for one event. Like the following:

```
 :complete=>(:fade, "uxLoader", :duration=>1 AND :fade, "uxTheOtherDiv", :duration=>1)
```

How do i achieve this.? I am using jrails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
:complete=>update_page do |page|
            page.visual_effect :fade, "uxLoader", :duration=>1
            page.visual_effect :fade, "uxTheOtherDiv", :duration=>1
           end
```

See [the api.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M001656)

Comment: thanks..is the order in which we give going to be the queue order?

Comment: Do you refer to chaining the effects? If thats the case its better to write javascript code like the comment above. Because the chaining is a javascript library specific function. You can do like this:
    :complete => "$('uxLoader').fadeIn(1000,function() {  $('uxTheOtherDiv').fadeIn(1000));});"

Answer (score 0):

Using straight jQuery?

```
:complete => "$('uxLoader').fadeIn(1000); $('uxTheOtherDiv').fadeIn(1000);"
```

Comment: inside your :complete you can just write the javascript; so just replace your :complete line with mine above. This is how i do it all the time.